# Spring Boot, Spring MVC webjars dependencies return 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webjars

I can`t join webjars dependencies to my html page in spring mvc. This is my pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use webjars-locator, so i dont need to add webjars to resource handlers manually. But when i load my page it returns 404 for each of webjars dependecies.

```
<script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/stomp-websocket/stomp.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your configuration and you should be fine.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/")
                .resourceChain(false);
        registry.setOrder(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth to check, if you have dependency-conflicts.
In my case I had

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-treetable</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

jquery-treetable itself depends on

```
    jquery 3.6.2
```

so both versions then were added to the libraries.

This leeds to an 404 when running the application.

You can detect this error by adding

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <dependencyConvergence/>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

to your build.